# eBay listing without DOCTYPE

Tags: doctype, ebay-design-templates

I created a eBay listing template generator.
It seemed to work find with Firefox and IE.

When we started to apply that to the real environment, we found out that the page looked bad in IE8.
I figured out that eBay removes DOCTYPE automatically and IE8 renders it in Quirk mode.
I searched for a solution and all answers said that I have to design it without DOCTYPE.
That's too much for me now.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Emulating IE7 should allow the listing design to remain the same in IE7 and also IE8. Let me know if this helps.